# Is it possible to create secondary store?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

Nowadays we see lots of local app stores for iOS and Android all over the world, at least there is 2 legal app stores else than Google Play in my country.

Is it possible to create a custom store like that for windows phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are custom ROMs for some WP devices (googleable); also, if you developer unlock the phone officially, you can install apps (up to 10) via datacable.

But there's no quick "allow 3rd party" setting like on Android, so running a store for casual users is unrealistic.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to create a new Store on Windows Phone. You can however distribute Enterprise Applications to devices that are enrolled with your organization. See [this topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206943(v=vs.105).aspx) for more information.

Comment: Added a link to Enterprise App distribution